# Puppet - Adding default nodes

Tags: module, nodes, puppet

I'm new to Puppet and following this tutorial to get into it:
http://www.pindi.us/blog/getting-started-puppet

I created an SSH module (/modules/ssh/manifests/init.pp) and added the following in the base node.pp (puppet/manifests/)

```
node default {  
include ssh  
}
```

The ssh module loks ike this:

```
class ssh {
    include ssh::install, ssh::config, ssh::service
  }

class ssh::install {
  package {"ssh":
    ensure => present,
    }
  }

class ssh::config {

  file { "/etc/ssh/sshd_config":
  ensure => present,
  owner => 'root',
  group => 'root',
  mode => 600,
  source => "puppet:///modules/ssh/sshd_config",
  notify => Class["ssh::service"],
      }
  }

class ssh::service {
  service { "ssh":
    ensure => running,
    hasstatus => true,
    hasrestart => true,
    enable => true,
    }
  }

Class["ssh::install"] -> Class["ssh::config"] -> Class["ssh::service"]
```

On the puppet I linked the module path with:

```
sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/vagrant/modules /vagrant/manifests/site.pp
```

which works.

If I then apply the nodes.pp I get the error:

```
Could not find class ssh for precise32 at /vagrant/manifests/nodes.pp:2 on node precise32...
```

Everything looks right, but I don't know where my error is.

It worked before as I installed SSH on the puppet yesterday, but I must have messed up something

Comment: What do you mean by "linked the module path"? What do you expect the first `puppet apply` to accomplish? What is the exact invocation when applying `nodes.pp` and what is the full path to your module? Please update your question with these details.

Comment: As @FelixFrank stated... pretty hard to troubleshoot without knowing how your invoking `puppet apply` on your `nodes.pp`